# mysql - LEFT JOIN not returning all rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

### What I have

**Problem:** My LEFT JOIN is not returning all the data from the left table.

Here are my table schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE item_to_map
  (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    map_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    INDEX(item_id),
    INDEX(map_id),
    INDEX(date),

    FOREIGN KEY (item_id)
      REFERENCES item (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES user (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (map_id)
      REFERENCES map (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
  );

CREATE TABLE vote_item
  (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    item_to_map_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    score ENUM("-1", "1"),

    INDEX(user_id),
    INDEX(item_to_map_id),
    INDEX(date),
    UNIQUE(user_id, item_to_map_id),

    FOREIGN KEY (item_to_map_id)
      REFERENCES item_to_map (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES user (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
  );
```

Here's the data I have so far in `vote_item` (ignore the fact that `user_id` maps to multiple `item_to_map_id`)

```
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+-------+
| id | user_id | item_to_map_id | date                | score |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+-------+
|  1 |      12 |              1 | 2017-07-05 09:41:32 | 1     |
|  2 |      12 |              1 | 2017-07-05 09:41:32 | 1     |
|  3 |      12 |              1 | 2017-07-05 09:41:33 | 1     |
|  4 |      12 |              2 | 2017-07-05 09:45:29 | 1     |
|  5 |      12 |              2 | 2017-07-05 09:45:29 | -1    |
|  6 |      12 |              2 | 2017-07-05 09:45:29 | -1    |
|  7 |      12 |              3 | 2017-07-05 09:56:28 | 1     |
|  8 |      12 |              3 | 2017-07-05 09:56:29 | -1    |
+----+---------+----------------+---------------------+-------+
```

Here's the `item_to_map` table:

```
+----+---------+--------+---------+---------------------+
| id | item_id | map_id | user_id | date                |
+----+---------+--------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |     20 |      12 | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |
|  2 |       1 |     20 |      12 | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |
|  3 |       1 |     20 |      12 | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |
|  4 |       2 |     20 |      12 | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |
|  5 |       2 |     20 |      12 | 2017-07-05 09:38:23 |
|  6 |       2 |     20 |      12 | 2017-07-05 09:38:24 |
+----+---------+--------+---------+---------------------+
```

### What I've tried

```
SELECT
  i.id,
  i.item_id,
  v.item_to_map_id,
  IFNULL( SUM(CAST(CAST(v.score AS char) AS SIGNED)), 0 ) AS score
FROM item_to_map i
LEFT JOIN
  vote_item v ON i.id = v.item_to_map_id
GROUP BY v.item_to_map_id;
```

But this returns

```
+----+---------+----------------+-------+
| id | item_id | item_to_map_id | score |
+----+---------+----------------+-------+
|  4 |       2 |           NULL |     0 |
|  1 |       1 |              1 |     3 |
|  2 |       1 |              2 |    -1 |
|  3 |       1 |              3 |     0 |
+----+---------+----------------+-------+
```

### What I expected

I expected id 5 and 6 to also show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate by all the (unaggregated) columns and fix your problem:

```
SELECT i.id, i.item_id, v.item_to_map_id,
       COALESCE( SUM(CAST(CAST(v.score AS char) AS SIGNED)), 0 ) AS score
FROM item_to_map i LEFT JOIN
     vote_item v
     ON i.id = v.item_to_map_id
GROUP BY i.id, i.item_id, v.item_to_map_id;
```

Comment: Is there a reason to group by all the unaggregated columns?

Comment: @A.Lau. . . That is the right way to use SQL.  You are using a MySQL (mis)feature -- whether you know it or not -- and your SQL would not run in most other databases.