# LEFT JOIN to return all results of of first table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have this SQL query ($product_id = 1)

```
SELECT
    attribute.*,
    attribute_description.*,
    product_attribute.*
FROM
    attribute
INNER JOIN attribute_description ON attribute.attribute_id = attribute_description.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN product_attribute ON attribute.attribute_id = product_attribute.attribute_id
WHERE
    product_attribute.product_id = '.$product_id .'
GROUP BY
    attribute.attribute_id,
    attribute_description.attribute_id,
    product_attribute.attribute_id
```

Table examples:

```
attribute
+----+--------------+--------------------+
| id | attribute_id | attribute_group_id |
+----+--------------+--------------------+
|  1 |            1 |                  1 | 
|  2 |            2 |                  1 |
|  3 |            3 |                  1 |
|  4 |            4 |                  1 |
|  5 |            5 |                  1 |
|  6 |            6 |                  1 |
+----+--------------+--------------------+

attribute_description
+----+--------------+--------------------+
| id | attribute_id |               name |
+----+--------------+--------------------+
|  1 |            1 |   attribute name 1 | 
|  2 |            2 |   attribute name 2 |
|  3 |            3 |   attribute name 3 |
|  4 |            4 |   attribute name 4 |
|  5 |            5 |   attribute name 5 |
|  6 |            6 |   attribute name 6 |
+----+--------------+--------------------+

product_attribute
+----+--------------+--------------------+
| id | attribute_id |         product_id | 
+----+--------------+--------------------+
|  1 |            1 |                  1 | 
|  2 |            2 |                  1 |
|  3 |            3 |                  1 |
|  4 |            4 |                  2 |
|  5 |            5 |                  2 |
|  6 |            6 |                  2 |
+----+--------------+--------------------+

What i am hoping to achieve: (expected output)
+----+--------------+--------------------+-------------+
| id | attribute_id |               name |  product_id |
+----+--------------+--------------------+-------------+
|  1 |            1 |   attribute name 1 |           1 |
|  2 |            2 |   attribute name 2 |           1 |
|  3 |            3 |   attribute name 3 |           1 |
|  4 |            4 |   attribute name 4 |        NULL |
|  5 |            5 |   attribute name 5 |        NULL |
|  6 |            6 |   attribute name 6 |        NULL |
+----+--------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

I would like to get all contents of tables **attribute** and **attribute_description** as well as the 3 results from **product_attribute** that satisfies the where clause.

Unfortunately i am only getting 3 results returned when i add the last LEFT JOIN and WHERE clause, where from my understanding i should receive all results from the first two tables.

I tried to understand here [mysql - LEFT JOIN not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44915391/mysql-left-join-not-returning-all-rows) though i am not sure i understand it correctly, though the question does seem similar.

I did try to group by all tables but without success.

Hoping someone might be able to point me in the correct direction so i can understand my problem to fix it.

Comment: Move condition from WHERE to ON.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, i will remove the group by clause and read through your resource.

Comment: See also about sql injection, and the importance of prepared and bound queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the filtering condition to the `on` clause:

```
FROM attribute a JOIN
     attribute_description ad
     ON a.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id LEFT JOIN
     product_attribute pa
     ON pa.attribute_id = p.attribute_id AND
        pa.product_id = '.$product_id .'
```

Your version doesn't work because it returns `NULL` for `product_id` on non-matching rows.  The `WHERE` clause filters those out.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have the where clause. The where clause makes your result only showing 3 rows. If you want to have attribute and it's description all shown for specific product perhaps you could change the condition on WHERE clause to the LEFT JOIN like this

```
    SELECT attribute.*, attribute_description.*, product_attribute.*  
FROM attribute  
INNER JOIN attribute_description ON attribute.attribute_id
    = attribute_description.attribute_id  
LEFT JOIN product_attribute ON attribute.attribute_id = product_attribute.attribute_id  
AND product_attribute.product_id = '.$product_id .'  
GROUP BY attribute.attribute_id, attribute_description.attribute_id, product_attribute.attribute_id
```

This all happens because after left joining your product_id is null and you add where clause to exact your input

Comment: @Strawberry And why is that? I understand now the where clause was applying it's condition to all records and records with null are filtered out. Gee.

Answer (score 0):

when you use left join and need all records of other tables on rigth side ,you should not place your condition of that table on "where" clause.because all recoreds are filtered by where clause.so you should use your condition in "ON"